# Javafx make combobox expand upward

Tags: javafx

I have a window which has a combobox at the bottom. When I click on it, not all the options are visible because they are not inside the screen area anymore. How can I make the drop-down list display upwards instead of downards?

I have the ComboBox defined in SceneBuilder. I define it in my code this way:
@FXML
ComboBox fontsComboBox;

In my initialize() method of the controller assigned to that window I have set some properties:

```
    fontComboBox.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    fontComboBox.getItems().addAll(fontList);
    fontComboBox.setValue(fontList[0]);
```

I'm pretty sure I need to add something here in order to make the dropdown list fo up.

Thanks,
Serban

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a known bug till Java 8u45. It is fixed in Java 8u60.

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092942 (fixed in **8u60**)

You can download JDK/JRE 8u60ea (early access) here to give it a try: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Java 8 Update 60 is scheduled GA for August 2015.

This example shows the problem. Simply open the combobox, even if you move the window down to screen, it won't show the list above the box.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxTester extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
      values.add(i);
    }
    ObservableList<Integer> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(values);
    ComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(items);
    comboBox.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(0);
    comboBox.setVisibleRowCount(5);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setBottom(comboBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

### Java 8 Update 45 behaviour

[image: Wrong ComboBox]

### Java 8 Update 60 ea behaviour

[image: Correct ComboBox]

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was going for