# How to change listcell opening orientation in combobox in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a combobox in my application, it is located at the bottom of the app (in full screen).

I find myself sometimes with the listcell coming out of the screen.

Is it possible to force the listcell to open upwards and not downwards?

I use MFXLegacyComboBox item.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javafx make combobox expand upward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034212/javafx-make-combobox-expand-upward)

Comment: @mikyll98 I use AdoptOpenJDK11 so I don't really understand this should be solved

Comment: It _could_ be a regression, but I can't reproduce it in recent version of Java 8, 11 or 17. If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Try using a [standard JavaFX Combo Box](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) in a recent JavaFX distribution, rather than a 3rd party material legacy combo box.  Does a recent version of the standard combo box work?